# Multilabel classification

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, keras

I working with a multilabel classification problem, using Keras, scikit-learn, etc...

My dataframe contain 4000 microscopic oil samples, with images and 13 different labels for which problem find in those samples.

Actually i convert all images and labels to numpy array.

Example of one labeled image:

[ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]

In this label, if position is equal to 1, that means the current sample have a specific problem, like some particles in oil, and as you can see, it's possible the sample have more than one output.

Well, the problem is, my dataframe are imbalanced and i need to apply Class Weight method, but before, looking at the labels, i think i need to use like:  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, ... ], not like the example i gave above.

Detail, i can run my neural network code without class weight, works well, but i can't train all the model with that imbalanced data.
Already tryed working using lists, unsuccessfully!

Of course, i have problems with shape, images have in example: (1000, 100, 200, 3) and labels (1000, 13); Thats why i can't apply Class Weight too...

There is a few problems i trying to fix.

I will post my code, because i stuck and i don't know what to do.

`class_weight_list = compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(Y_train), Y_train)
    class_weight = dict(zip(np.unique(Y_train), class_weight_list))
    Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train,num_classes=len(np.unique(Y_train)))`

[main.py](https://pastebin.com/byrFfEZT)

[dataset.py](https://pastebin.com/GgG3bkYq)

[models.py](https://pastebin.com/FbXvXVwE)

What is the best strategy to work with labels in this case?
I appreciate if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!!